# Wamp server Put Online is not working

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I did the following steps to setup Wamp, but not able to access the server from different machine in the network. What am I doing wrong?

1. Installed Wamp 64 Bit Version 3.0.4 this comes with Apache version 2.4.18
2. Started Wamp server, right click on system tray icon, choose `Menu item : Online / Offline` under `Wamp settings`
3. Click on (left click) system tray icon and chose `Put Online`
4. When I try to access the server from another machine in the network, the server return a error page with error message `You don't have permission to access / on this server`

I directly edited httpd-vhosts.conf file and restarted all the service, still getting the same error. Below is the content of httpd-vhosts.conf file and my system IP

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot C:/Users/dinesh/Softwares/Wamp64/www
    <Directory  "C:/Users/dinesh/Softwares/Wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 100.97.67
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

System IP

```
mintty> ipconfig | grep IPv4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 100.97.67.11
mintty>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
 #
 # Virtual Hosts
 #

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
        <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require local
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
 #
```

REPLACE BY

```html
 #
 # Virtual Hosts
 #

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
        <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            #Require local
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
 #
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Put Online/ Offline` menu item has been made optional, and invisible by default, as it basically has no function anymore in WAMPServer 3.

In WAMPServer 3 there is now a Virtual Hosts defined for `localhost` and that takes presidence over the localhost defined in the `httpd.conf` file.

If you look at the new menus structure there is a new menu item in the Apache menu called `httpd-vhosts.conf` see below

[image]

This will load the Apache Virtual Host definition file into your defautl editor. It should look like this :

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

To allow access from specific machines on your network add for example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.1.100
        Require ip 192.168.1.101
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or to allow all the PC's in your network access add just the first 3 of the 4 quartiles to the `require` and any ip will be allowed within that subnet

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

> If you do not see this menus then you will need to upgrade to WAMPServer 3.0.5 from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Updates/wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.0.5.exe/download
>   It is a simple upgrade over WAMPServer 3.0.4

Alternatively, just edit the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file directly.

> Dont forget to restart Apache after changing this file.

Comment: there is no httpd-vhosts.conf in my menu

Comment: I added some more info to my answer

Comment: I made changes to httpd-vhosts.conf and restarted all services, still getting the same error

Comment: Edit your question and add your httpd-vhosts.conf file for me to look at

Comment: I have made changes in the question to show httpd-vhosts.conf file content

Comment: 100.97.67 is not a local network address that is a publicly visible internet address

Comment: It works if I install Wamp 2.5 38 Bit in a different directory and run this instead of the earlier Wamp variant

Comment: ?? 38bit ?? WAMPServer 2.5 is older than WAMPServer 3.0.x

Comment: Are you sure you installed all the required MSVC runtime libraries [See here for a list](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295) there was also a list in the first dialog of the WAMPServer3.anything install

Comment: sorry its 32 Bit and yes its a older version and older version works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you have done everything suggested by other answers but still it is not working then make sure your port 80 is not used by other application.

To check it quickly run **netstat -a -b** command in Command Prompt.

In my case Skype was using port 80, that I could stop by going into Skype's advanced settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had an irritating problem. Windows firewall had a rule to let apache through, but it was a previous version of apache, and therefor didn't work for the new. Had to update the version of apache in the rule and add it to private-section. Windows 10.